# Media Queries Not Working on Mobile Devices

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

[Site](http://bit.ly/1i2b6xj)

The above site has bootstrap @ media queries using max-width and min-width which works when I resize my desktop browser window. But for some reason I am seeing the site as a desktop version and the media queries to make it responsive are not showing up in mobile devices.

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: I've checked your site and since you hid the horizontal scrollbar, you should collapse the navbar under like 500px width regardless of the device. This is just a tip completely off the topic.

Comment: I will say that your question has been downvoted several times. Likely due to the fact that the question is not very detailed.

Answer (score 2):

You've just forgotten to set the viewport width by adding the viewport meta tag to the page. Pop this in your page header somewhere within the `<head>` section.

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

Have a look at the Basic Example in the [Bootstrap Docs](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#template) to see how they suggest you use the tag.

EDIT: I just found this fairly [long guide on what the viewport tag is](http://quirksmode.org/presentations/Autumn2012/viewports_fronteers.pdf) and what it's actually used for so if your interested give it a look.

Answer (score -1):

here's an example of some of the isues you have with your media queries on the site:

```
media="screen"
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px)
#Intro {
max-height: 230px;
}
staging.shipmenthq.com/media="screen"
@media only screen and (max-width: 467px)
#Intro {
min-height: 300px;
}
```

So your max-height & min-height are conflicting.

As far as non-responsive; I'm seeing that the .navbar and none of it's children have any media queries attached, so this won't respond.

It looks like you need to go through your media queries to rework them from the ground up, as you have some overlap & cascade issues.

Comment: I don't think he's looking for inconsistencies within his media queries, he's looking for a reason as to why the media queries are not working when browsed using a mobile device. My solution (adding the viewport meta tag) corrects the issue in his question.

Comment: @WilliamPatton - good catch, I was focused on the unsustainable way the media queries were written.

Comment: yeah if the media queries have more sections like this then the rules need to be rewritten/rearranged, that's for sure. At least he can now get it working on on mobile devices - whether it looks good or cascades into an overly processor intensive re-rendering mess remains to be seen haha

Comment: Also I'd like to point out that it wasn't me who downvoted your answer :p

Answer (score -1):

I see no issue with the site you've linked. Its responsive from what I can see.

If you are saying that your top menu (header menu) isn't displaying as it should for a Bootstrap site, I should say that you are missing few divs in navbar section.

If you add them back, it will look like what it is supposed to look like.

e.g.:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
    <!-- navbar header div -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
        <!-- navbar collapse btn -->
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="brand pull-left" href="#Intro"><img src="images/logo.png" width="201" height="38" alt="ShipmentHQ"></a>

        <span class="phoneNumber pull-right"><img src="images/phonenumber.png" alt="call us at 888-234-5678" width="174" height="24"></span>
    <!-- navbar collapse div -->

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav pull-right">
          <li><a class="NavLink" href="#Services">Services</a></li>
          <li><a class="NavLink" href="#About">About</a></li>
          <li><a class="NavLink" href="#ResourcesHead">Resources</a></li>
          <li><a class="NavLink" href="#Contact">Contact</a></li>
```

here is what you need.

Hope this helps.